# Eclipse plugin: checking that the interface has loaded

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm building a eclipse plugin that does various things within an editor - the problem is that my code loads and starts (I believe) before the UI code loads and so I get null pointer errors on start up.

I couldn't find a 'isTheInterfaceLoaded()' method lying around so I'm using the following code to check if the interface is up.

```
public static boolean areWeOnline() {
    IFile file = null;
    IWorkbenchWindow win = getWorkBenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
    if (page != null) {
        IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
        if (editor != null) {
            IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();
            if (input instanceof IFileEditorInput) {
                file = ((IFileEditorInput) input).getFile();
            }
        }
    }
    if (file == null) {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
//JR got to be a better way - stackoverflow it?
}
```

(Comment is genuinely in the code) - now this works, but I'm certain there must be some other, more elegant way of doing this - any ideas?

Comment: What's causing your code to run?  Is it your activator, and if so, what's causing your bundle to activate?

Comment: Clearly there is a problem with the way you are starting up. Is all of this in a single plugin? How are you getting to the code that needs to check? If you are waiting for you editor to inistialize, you might need some state variable that flags when initialization is complete.

Can you describe the environment of your problem more completely?